# How to close Iframe selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, parsing, iframe, aliexpress

the iframe is the first banner from aliexpress.com
I get the local selector to close button, but cant to switch to iframe. Unfortunately, I don't know the id of the iframe.
Already try to get elements by selectors "iframe", did not work for me.
Is there any way how to get iframe without id, or get the id, or close iframe outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove that frame it using Javascript:

```java
@Test
public void iframe(){
    driver.get("https://aliexpress.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement iFrame = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions
                    .presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'campaign.aliexpress.com')]")));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
            .executeScript("arguments[0].remove();", iFrame);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='product-item'][1]")).click();
}
```

**P.S.** - there are quite a lot of other banners so it is worth having your browser window maximized.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab it by xPath and then switchTo() to frame. Another option is to use selenium driver as JavascriptExecutor and and invoke a js script with that frame as a root node.